# swagger-maven-plugin: manipulate the method path

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

I have this JAX-RS Controller

```java
@Component
@Path("/mypath")
public class MyController {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test() {
    }
}
```

When I generate YAML with the Swagger Maven plugin the Path is
/mypath/test

But I have configured the webserver before to run the App under /api.
So it will be
/api/mypath/test
for the users.

How can I do that with the Swagger Maven Plugin?

I have investigated the documentation and debugged the plugin but I can't find any possibility.